# How to stop Netbeans from double quoting command line arguments

Tags: netbeans, opensuse

I have a problem with Netbeans automatically double quoting each of the command line arguments set in Project Properties -> Run -> Run Command.
Since I would like to redirect the command line output to a file with `> dump.txt` this is a problem. Wrapping the dump command in `` doesnt help.
I tried to run it in different terminals but they all get those double quoted arguments passed to them...

Is this a problem with Netbeans, am I missing a setting, or is it OpenSUSE related (I dont have this problem under lubuntu)?

PS: Netbeans version 7.0.1

Comment: Are you sure it's not the reverse?  the shell automatically splits on whitespace. netbeans probably doesn't,  since it's not using a shell.  `>` is shell syntax. it's not really an argument.

Comment: What Janus said: if you want to have the output stored in the file, either Ctrl-S in the output window, or invoke the application from shell with `> dump.txt`. Or build an option into your app to have dump filename provided as an actual parameter.

Comment: Yes, I know > is not an argument, I just called it that because its at the end of my argument list in the Run Command field of Netbeans. But still the external terminal lists > dump.txt in double quotes (in the header line of the terminal the actual command is not shown on the command line of the terminal just an error because > dump.txt is an invalid argument to my program) thus not evaluating it as a shell command. I am just not sure "who" inserts those double quotes. They are not there in the Run Command field, but in the terminal each argument has them.